# HashSet iteration

Tags: java, iterator, hashset

I have a query regarding iterator of HashSet in Java.
In book "Java Generics and Collections", following is stated:

> The chief attraction of a hash table implementation for sets is the (ideally) constanttime
>   performance for the basic operations of add, remove, contains, and size. Its main
>   disadvantage is its iteration performance; since iterating through the table involves
>   examining every bucket, its cost is proportional to the table size regardless of the size
>   of the set it contains.

It states that iterator looks in every bucket of underlying table. But going through actual implementation(JDK 8), I see that HashIterator stores next node
reference. So it seems iterator doesn't need to visit every single bucket.

Is book wrong here OR my understanding is wrong?

Comment: Are you looking through the code for a `LinkedHashMap` or a `HashMap`?

Comment: I am looking into HashMap and when I debugged to see which iterator is returned for a HashSet then I see that KeyIterator in HashMap is returned,which in turn extends HashIterator.HashIterator keeps record of next node.

Comment: According to the [Javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html), "Iterating over this set requires time proportional to the sum of the HashSet instance's size (the number of elements) plus the "capacity" of the backing HashMap instance (the number of buckets). Thus, it's very important not to set the initial capacity too high (or the load factor too low) if iteration performance is important."

Answer (score 3):

The document is right. Although `KeyIterator` indeed calls `nextNode().key`, like this

```
final class KeyIterator extends HashIterator implements Iterator<K> {
    public final K More ...next() {
        return nextNode().key;
    }
}
```

the code for `nextNode()` in the base class `HashIterator` has the loop that the documentation is talking about:

```
final Node<K,V> nextNode() {
    Node<K,V>[] t;
    Node<K,V> e = next;
    if (modCount != expectedModCount)
        throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
    if (e == null)
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    if ((next = (current = e).next) == null && (t = table) != null) {
        do {} while (index < t.length && (next = t[index++]) == null);
    }
    return e;
}
```

The `do`/`while` loop with an empty body traverses the buckets one by one, looking for the next entry.

The only time this may be relevant is when you iterate over a hash set which you pre-allocated with a large number of buckets, but have not populated with a large number of items yet. When you let your `HashSet` grow by itself as you add more items, the number of buckets will be proportional to the number of items that you inserted so far, so the slowdown would not be significant.