# NoSuchElementException using Iterator class with HashSet

Tags: java, android

I don't udnerstand why this code is giving me a `NoSuchElementException`

Essentially what I'm doing is iterating across a `HashSet` of `Gatt` servers and closing their connections with a device if their device addresses match.

```
BluetoothDevice device = mDeselectedDeviceData.device;
Iterator<BluetoothGatt> it = BleManager.getInstance().myGattConnections.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    if(it.next().getDevice().getAddress() == device.getAddress()){ 
        it.next().close();
    }
}
```

This line

```
if(it.next().getDevice().getAddress() == device.getAddress()){
```

is throwing the error

```
>NoSuchElementException
```

However, `it.hasNext()` has is true if I log it

```
while (it.hasNext()) {
    Log.(TAG,"it.hasNext() is "+String.valueOf(it.hasNext())); // Prints true
    if(it.next().getDevice().getAddress() == device.getAddress()){ 
        it.next().close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HashSet iteration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32035709/hashset-iteration)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if(it.next().getDevice().getAddress() == device.getAddress()){ 
    it.next().close();
}
```

You call `it.next()` *twice* here, and it advances the iterator two positions.  I'm pretty sure what you mean here is

```
BluetoothGatt gatt = it.next();
if(gatt.getDevice().getAddress() == device.getAddress()){ 
    gatt.close();
}
```

Comment: Yes, exactly, thank you. But now if there is only one GATT server, I cannot make the comparison because `it.next()` is false. Isn't there like an it.current() method or something? Sorry for the stupid question.

Comment: No, there is not.  You can only extract elements using `.next()`, and if you want to use that more than once you must store it in a variable.

Comment: Okay, I think I got it. If there is only one element in the set, it.next() will return the first element in the set the first time it's called. Thanks.